# How to defferent row heights for different rows in a single table?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html, so please try to understand if i am making any silly mistake.
I am trying to create a login window like face book. i have created a login window which looks like following:
[image]

Here i have taken a table of 2 rows first row renders 2 text boxes and a login button. second consists of 'remember me' and 'forgor password' link.
Problem is that i want 2nd row of height 12px and text "remember me " to  be shown in exact center of check box not as its looking a bit down in above image.
I have written some temporary inline cssto check out look:
following is my code for this section:

```
 <table style="float:left;margin-top:1%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right: 0px;background:blue;">
                                    <div class="uiStickyPlaceholderInput uiStickyPlaceholderEmptyInput">
                                        <input type="text" style=" width:110px;text-align:center;"class="inputtext _5aju" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" tabindex="1" value="" aria-label="Email or Phone">
                                    </div>
                               </td>

                               <td style="padding-right: 0px;background:red">
                                     <div class="uiStickyPlaceholderInput">
                                       <input type="password" style=" width:105px;text-align:center;float:right;" class="inputtext _5aju" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" value="" aria-label="Password">
                                     </div>
                                </td>

                                <td >
                                     <button value="1" class="_42ft _42fu _5ajv selected _42g- btn btn-primary btn-small" id="loginbutton" tabindex="4" type="submit">Log In</button>
                                </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr height="12" style="background:pink;">
                                <td height="10">
                                    <span class="_5ajw">
                                        <div>   
                                            <label class="_5bb4">
                                                 <input id="persist_box" style="height:10px;background:yellow" type="checkbox" name="persistent" value="1" tabindex="3">
                                                 <span style="font-size:10px;margin-top:-5px;background:yellow">Remember me</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="default_persistent" value="0">
                                         </div>
                                   </span>
                                 </td>

                                 <td  style="margin-top:-1%;">
                                     <a class="_5ajx" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.google.com" 
                                     style="font-size:10px;paddig-left:2px;margin-top:-1%;background:yellow;">Forgot your password?</a>
                                 </td>
                         </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
```

So,please can any one tell me how to adjust css to achive above mentioned.
thanks in advance. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try vertical-align:middle on the span containing the Remember me text.

On a side note, I would advice you to avoid tables for this kind of layout and achieve the same layout using divs.

Comment: Thanx @code.tweetie, it worked.But Please, can you tell me how to reduce height of second row so that it would be the same height of the text

Comment: I hate to tell you to try the following : {margin:0} on the checkbox & for td {line-height:11px;margin:0;padding:0}

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you shouldn't use a table for layout purposes.

In your example, I would try removing the margins around the checkbox, leaving only the right margin like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="default_persistent" value="0" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;>
```

That should do the trick.